# What does this Hadith Mean: "The Qur'an was collected in the lifetime of the Prophet (ﷺ) by four..."

Tags: hadith-interpretation

In this Hadith which is found in Bukhari and Muslim it says:

> Anas Ibn Maalik said, "The Qur'an was collected in the lifetime of the Prophet (ﷺ) by four (men), all of whom were from the Ansar: Ubai, Mu`adh bin Jabal, Abu Zaid and Zaid bin Thabit. 
> **[ [Sunnah Ref: Bukhari 3810](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3810) ]** 
> **[ [Sunnah Ref: Muslim 2465a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2465a) ]**

And I want to know what "collected" means here.

Does it mean these four men compiled a physical mushaf or does it mean they memorised the Qur'an?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 'collected in their chests' i.e. learned and memorized. In the same sense that the Quran says:

> #### لا تحرك به لسانك لتعجل به
>
> #### إن علينا جمعه وقرآنه
>
> Move not your tongue with it, [O Muhammad], to hasten with recitation of the Qur'an.
>
> Indeed, upon Us is its collection [in your heart] and [to make possible] its recitation.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 75:16-17](https://quran.com/75/16-17?translations=20)</sup>

> ‏{‏إن علينا جمعه وقرآنه‏}‏ أن نجمعه في صدرك
>
> 'It is for Us to collect it' means we will collect it in your chest
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari 4928](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4928) and [Muslim 448a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:448a)</sup>

And there are many other examples of texts in ahadith and athar of the sahaba where 'collecting the Quran' is used to refer to one who is a Hafiz, such as [Bukhari 5036](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5036), [Abu Dawud 587](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:587), [Ibn Majah 1346](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1346), [Jami at-Tirmidhi 2382](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2382) etc.

At least some of these Sahaba were also [scribes](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/20968/) and wrote down verses of the Quran on physical objects during the lifetime of the Prophet ﷺ. However, I am not aware of any evidence that they compiled a bound paper mushaf at that point, rather it is known that it was done later during the caliphate of Abu Bakr.

> قوله جمع القرآن أي استظهره حفظا
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3868)</sup>